# How to access parameter in a join table in many to many assotiation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many, relationship, nested-attributes

I have 2 models which are connected as many-to-many via third model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :workspaces
end

class Workspace < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class UserWorkspace < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :workspace
  enum role: [:user, :admin]
end
```

Unfortunately I can not find out how to access the parameter `role` for UserWorkspace. for example, `@workspace.user.last.role` does not work. Please could you help?

Comment: Can you post the error ?

Comment: it looks like this: undefined method `role' for #<User:0x007f8abde91728>